# adding time from one timestamp field to other field

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I'm trying to add the time (hours minutes and seconds) from the user initial date to the current date but I received an errors.

I don't know what I do wrong, open to other suggestions

```
select distinct uid,
       min (ts) over (partition by uid order by ts rows unbounded preceding) as initial_date,
       current_date-2 + interval 'to_char(min (ts) over (partition by uid order by ts rows unbounded preceding),'HH') hours'
  from mr_session_log
where ts >= '2015-09-01'
```

and this the error I've recevied

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "') hours'"
```

Position: 355

```
current_date-2 + interval 'to_char(min (ts) over (partition by uid order by ts rows unbounded preceding),'HH') hours',
                                                                                                               ^
```

Comment: current_date-2? Is that an identifier name or are you trying to substract something from that field? Also the syntax highlight does a good job on suggesting what's wrong but still you should always post the error message.

Comment: hi , i've added the error, current_date - 2 reducing 2 days from the current_date

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be overengineering the solution, the syntax highlight shows clearly that you can't put functions in interval and there is no need for window functions when you want distinct uid and partition by uid.

```
SELECT uid, (current_date -2 ) + min(ts::time)
FROM mr_session_log
WHERE ts >= '2015-09-01'
GROUP BY uid
ORDER BY uid;
```

Comment: can i do that with windows function since i'm have more fields in the select?

Comment: @user3600910 Sure, the most important part were date/time operations, right? You should be able to figure the rest out.

Comment: @user3600910 maybe try to use subquery with window function and then at the higher level do rest of work needed

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use window function it is also quite simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    uid,
    CURRENT_DATE - 2 - MIN(ts::time) OVER (PARTITION BY uid
                                     ORDER BY ts
                                     ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS date_with_added_time
FROM mr_session_log
WHERE ts >= '2015-09-01'::DATE;
```

If you need only the hours and minutes and secconds use `MIN(date_trunc('secconds', ts)::time)` instead of `MIN(ts::time)`

Comment: what i need is to add inly the time to the current_date -2 that why i use to_chat

Comment: @user3600910 I've corrected my answer - you just need to cast `timestamp` to `time` or use `date_trunc(text, timestamp)` if millisecconds are useless